# Spring Java JPA is saving String as tinyblob, giving json parse error

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, jpa

I have two entities, with one to one relationship. I want one to be a parent, and other as a child:

Parent: MappingPayload with following code:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "duplicate_handling_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private DuplicateHandling duplicateHandling;
```

Child: DuplicateHandling with following code:

```
    public MappingPayload() {
    this.id = null;
}
private String dupAction;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "duplicateHandling")
    private MappingPayload mappingPayload;
```

The problem is with the private String dupAction in DuplicateHandling class. It is being saved in mysql as tinyblob which should be varchar. (Note that there are other String fields in other classes that are being correctly saved as varchar)

The problem is with DuplicateHandling class only, so if I add more String fields, they are also saved as tinyblob. I have tried changing the data type in database manually as well.

When I send the following json:

```
{ 
"mappingPayload":{
    "duplicateHandling": {"dupAction":"we are"}
```

}
}

I get the following error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String` 

(although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('we are'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.String` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('we are')
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 37] (through reference chain: com.amos.amosintegrationprocessor.requests.CreateMappingRequest["mappingPayload"]->com.amos.amosintegrationprocessor.entities.MappingPayload["duplicateHandling"]->com.amos.amosintegrationprocessor.entities.DuplicateHandling["dupAction"])]
```

This is version information from gradle file: 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.2'

Answer (score 0):

An object must be referenced as an entity. If you don't do it, jpa will consider it binary and put the serialized binary into a database column.

Solution 1) Make it an entity

Simply make it an entity means to annotate it with @Entity & Column mappings resulting in a new table

Solution 2) Make it embeddable

Using the @Embeddable annotation instead @OneToOne will make the properties of the class become nested into the parent's table representation.

```
@Entity
public class MappingPayload {
   
   @Embedded
   private DuplicateHandling duplicateHandling;
}
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class DuplicateHandling {
   private String json;
}
```

This will cause JPA to nest the columns from DuplicateHandling into the MappingPayload. This is no issue, because it was a 1:1 relation anyway before.

Always remember, a complex type like DuplicateHandling will become a blob if you store it into the database without telling JPA how to store it.

The embeddable trick will keep your strings staying strings.

General hint:

If you have structured data and a relational database, don't serialize json into a column unless their is a real need. If you just have a plain class, it's more versatile to make it a new entity and reference it. Plus it is more clean.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Note that Duplicate Handling is an Entity, at the moment I have removed all other fields but it will contain more data. Unfortunately all String attributes are giving json parse error and saved as tinyblob. I don't think I have understood your solutions, I will appreciate it if you could elaborate. Secondly, the second solution didnt work, Intelij wants me to remove it. I put the @Embaddable, on top of the privae DuplicateHandling duplicateHangling object in the parent MappingPayload field.

Comment: see the example please

Comment: also, you may want to check this https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable